# write to event log from web site project

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to log an error from a web site project to windows event viewer
but with no luck.

I tried to add another project within the website that contains function to write to event log and reference it in the website project. if i hit the using keyword in the page cs file the other project is not shown

Is it the right way to do this..?

if so, in the aspx page code behind i should use System.configuration and every time i want to write to event viewer then i have to call the method in the class i referenced to deal with it?

i want something like this:

```
try{
..
}
catch(Exception ex){
   writeToLogFunction(exception source, exception name, exception  description);
}
```

Is this is the right approach ? i never dealt with it before and appreciate any 
walk through \ example ..

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Open Source / free logging libraries out there. I've used these and they are very well done:

[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

[Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

This site lists quite a few logging libraries and well as some useful links that discuss how logging should be handled (at the bottom of the page)

[.NET Logging Tools and Libraries](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/)

Comment: I agree. I always think twice before using third party components rather than rolling out my own code. In this case though, you might want to reconsider. These components have been around for a while and take into account several features/functionality that would be time-consuming to implement. For example, most logging libraries will use a separate thread to log the error. This prevents the logging process from blocking the main/UI thread. They also allow you to change the location of the logging from DB to file system to event viewer with a simple change in the config file.